google-cloud/pubsub: Total timeout of API google.pubsub.v1.Publisher exceeded 60000 milliseconds before any response was received
When I use the library: @google-cloud/pubsub method to get the topic created in gcloud pub/sub, I get the following error:
Total timeout of API google.pubsub.v1.Publisher exceeded 60000 milliseconds before any response was received.
I have configured the ADC locally and set the environment variables, I think it is not caused by this.
version:
"@google-cloud/pubsub": "^4.5.0"
const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');

// Creates a client; cache this for further use
const pubSubClient = new PubSub();

async function listAllTopics() {
    // Lists all topics in the current project
    const [topics] = await pubSubClient.getTopics();
    console.log('Topics:');
    topics.forEach(topic => console.log(topic.name));
  }

function main(){
listAllTopics().catch(err => {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  });
 }

main()

Try to use the api key for authentication, but still get the same error
const pubSubClient = new PubSub({
    projectId: "demo",
    credentials: {
      client_email: "xxxxxxxxxx",
      private_key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    },
  });

gcloud cli can be used normally

Generally that error is an indication of an error talking to the server. If gcloud isn't doing it, there may be something like a proxy that the node stack isn't picking up. (It's a completely different software stack, node vs python.) Is this running on GCE/GKE?
